# ¿Por qué no funciona mi funcion Insertar para mis TDA lista y nodo?

Tags: c, lista, insert

Por favor ayudenme a solucionar esto, tengo mis TDA de esta forma (Así deben ser implementados):

```
typedef struct nodo {
    int byteinicial;
    int bytefinal;
    struct nodo *siguiente;
} nodo;

typedef struct {
    int posicion;
    int maximo;
    nodo *primero;
    nodo *ultimo;
    int largoactual;
} lista;
```

Se desea implementar un administrador de memoria dinámica, en la lista los nodos van ordenados de mayor a menor, cuando en los nodos un bytefinal tope con un byteinicial de otro nodo (osea que el bytefinal+1 es igual al bytefinal del que le sigue) se deben juntar como si fueran un único nodo.

Mi función insertar da Segmentation Fault..

```
void insertar(int binicial, int bfinal, lista *l){ 
    int i;
    nodo *nodonuevo, *actual, *post;         //Declaro los nodos que ocupare
    nodonuevo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));    
    nodonuevo -> byteinicial = binicial;        //Se crea el nodo que va a ser insertado
    nodonuevo-> bytefinal = bfinal;
    actual = l->primero;                        //El nodo actual (para el for) es el primero de la lista 
    if (l->largoactual==1 && binicial ==1){     //En caso de que solo haya un nodo en la lista
        l->primero = nodonuevo;
        l->ultimo = nodonuevo;
        return;
    }
    post = actual -> siguiente;                 //Es el nodo que le sigue al actual
    for (i = 1; i<l->largoactual; i++){         
        if (binicial == 1){             //En caso de que el nodonuevo deba ser el primero de la lista
            if (bfinal+1 == post->byteinicial){     //En caso de que el bytefinal del nodonuevo tope con el que le sigue
                nodonuevo->bytefinal = post->bytefinal;
                nodonuevo->siguiente = post->siguiente;
                l->primero = nodonuevo;
                free((void*)post);  
                break;
            }
            else{
                nodonuevo->siguiente = post;   
                l->primero = nodonuevo;
                l->largoactual++;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (binicial < post->byteinicial){         //Se ubica apenas sea menor que el byteinicial del nodo que le siga
            if (bfinal+1 == post->byteinicial){         //En caso de que tope con el nodo que le sigue
                nodonuevo->bytefinal = post->bytefinal;
                nodonuevo->siguiente = post->siguiente;
                actual->siguiente = nodonuevo;
                free((void*)post);
                break;
            }
            else{
                nodonuevo->siguiente = post;
                actual->siguiente = nodonuevo;
                l->largoactual++;
                break;

            }
        }
        else if (bfinal == l->maximo){              //En caso de que deba ser ubicado al final de la lista
            nodonuevo->siguiente = NULL;
            actual->siguiente=nodonuevo;
            l->largoactual++;
            l->ultimo=nodonuevo;
            break;
        }

        else{                               //Se actualizan para el proximo ciclo del for
            actual = post;
            post = actual->siguiente;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista no posee inconvenientes la función insertar.
El problema puede estar en tu función main. Al no inicializar lista, el puntero a nodo tiene valor indefinido, lo que te generaría segmentation fault. Tu función insertar no esta abarcando el caso para cuando la lista esta vacía:

```
 actual = l->primero;                        //El nodo actual (para el for) es el primero de la lista 
    if (l->largoactual==1 && binicial ==1){     //En caso de que solo haya un nodo en la lista
        l->primero = nodonuevo;
        l->ultimo = nodonuevo;
        return;
    }
```

Específicamente en esas líneas estás utilizando valores que obligatoriamente deben estar inicializados en la función main.